# How to open page with result like contactbook?

Tags: android, navigation, win-universal-app

In my UWP-App I want to create an app internal contactbook page. I can select a contact and return the selected contact back to the page where I opened the contactbook.

In Android where I come from there is a function called "startActivityForResult" which opens an activity gets the return value when finished.

I want to create the same behaviour.

I did this with `Frame.Navigate(typeof(ContactBook))` and then when the contact is selected I navigate back with `Frame.Navigate(typeof(PreviousPage), selectedContact)`

The method `Frame.GoBack()` is useless in this case because I can't pass a parameter.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You can store the selectedContact in localsettings and use that value

Comment: This is pretty ugly isn't it? Also the ContactBook from Windows 10 can implement this behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% familiar with android and "startActivityForResult" but are you looking to navigate the entire frame away?  There isn't any equivalent in UWP apps, nor is there even really one for WPF's showDialog(), which is probably what you're looking for.

You only have a few options and none of them are really "amazing" per-say.

You can do what you've done above, which is navigate away to the page that has all the contacts, then navigate to a new page but depending on how your app is layed out you might be losing data on the page (since it's a new instance and not a back in the stack so you can't really cache it).  You also can't navigate to an instance of a page either, it's only to a new page or through the stack from back / forward.   If you use GoBack though and cache the page (using the "required" mode for caching) then you could do some dirty lookup of a stored value in a static class (I know, ugly and not MVVM) or setting a local settings value and reading that in the OnNavigatedTo() method for the page before.

If you don't NEED to use frame movement, you can use a flyout or a custom flyout user control to build a popup of sorts that will display the XAML for the page instead of a page frame.  This will have a few difficulties with resizing (so more so for W10 than W10M) and such but you'll be able to not transition out of the frame itself.  Then you can see the value of the selected and then on the submit event, you can just work with the page since it's already open.

If need be you could build a custom usercontrol for the flyout and put some custom dependency properties that can be bound for MVVM, it really all depends on what and how you're doing it.

So short answer, there is no fast way of achieveing what you're looking for and that does seem like an issue with the API.   I would make the suggestion on the API's uservoice (https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform) and try to get it upvoted!

Answer (score 0):

> There isn't any equivalent in UWP apps, nor is there even really one for WPF's showDialog(), which is probably what you're looking for.

@Daniel, no, there is a equivalent in UWP apps. Please refer to [Launch an app for results](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-launch-an-app-for-results), you can follow the tutorial in that doc to achieve this.

To do this, you will need to create two apps. One is the app which will launch the result app (let say "main app"), the other app here should be the contact-book app. The contact-book app will behavior like a modal window, and the main app will wait for the result of the contact-book app.

But in an UWP app, you can use [ContactStore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.contacts.contactstore.aspx) class to access the database that contains contacts.

So, you will need to reconsider if that is necessary to create a contact app by yourself.

**Edit:**
I may misunderstand your question, you just want your page to behavior like contact-book, not want to create a contact-book by yourself. But anyway, it's the same, you can create another app to hold your page which you want to launch from your main app.

Comment: Thak you for your answer. I solverd the problem with using a singleton and after navigating I check this singleton for a value. Pretty ugly but it works.
I will accept the answer from daniel because he answered it first and you both have provides similar answers. So don't be mad at me.

Comment: @TableCreek, it's OK. But I don't think we are talking about the similar thing.